# How to import a file from the main container project inside share extension?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-app-extension, ios8-share-extension

I want to import a file/class I created in the main project inside an Application Extension. How can I achieve that?

File inside my main project:

```
struct MyConstants {
    static let = MaxChars = 100
}
```

In Share Extension:

```
import UIKit
import Social

class ShareViewController: SLComposeServiceViewController {
    let maxCharactersAllowed = MyConstants.MaxChars // Basically what I want to do
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be as easy as adding the file to your extension target/project so that both are part of the same module. Same module means internal scope and the constant should be accessible from the other file automatically.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html